# Sliding panel jQuery version issue

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery project which works great, here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/355uzcft/)

```
$('#toggle').toggle(function () {
            $('#A').animate({ width: 0 });
            $('#B').animate({ left: 0 });
}, function () {
            $('#A').animate({ width: 200 });
            $('#B').animate({ left: 200 });
});
```

My issue is my main project I want to use this script on uses jQuery 1.10.2 and for some reason this script isn't compatible with that version and I don't want to run two libraries, the toggle button vanishes when the page loads (using 1.10.2) not sure how to make it compatible, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The jquery `toggle` and `animate` functions are most definitely compatible with jQuery 1.10.2, so you have some sort of mess up in your main project like unclosed brackets that would cause this not to work. As we cannot see your main project, we cannot help you.

Comment: I have updated my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/355uzcft/1/ and changed the jQuery library to 1.10.2 and you will see the 'toggle' button disappear.